# axios request for image upload is not working from vue.js but working from postman

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, multer

I am using multer library for uploading image

this is my uploadFile.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
// storage engine 
export const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './upload/images',
  filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
    return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
  }
})
export const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000
  }
  })
```

this is my vue.js file

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" v-model="name" />
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label for="photo">photo</label>
      <input
        style="display: none"
        type="file"
        name="file"
        id="photo"
        @change="onFileSelected"
        ref="fileInput"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
      <button type="submit" class="md-primary md-raised">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
<script>

import request from "../../utils/request";
import FormData from "form-data";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      selectedFile: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    },
    onSubmit() {
   const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", this.selectedFile);
      formData.append("data", this.name);
      console.log(this.selectedFile);
      const res = request({
        url: "/project/create",
  formData,
        // headers: {
        //   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        // },
        //        headers: {
        //   'accept': 'application/json',
        //   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        //   'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${fd._boundary}`,
        // },
        method: "post",
      });
      console.log(res);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

in route using middleware

```
middlewares: [
            upload.single('file'),
        ],
```

this is my controller file

```
export const CreateController = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log("baseurl", req.baseUrl)
   console.log("headers", req.headers)
    console.log("profile", req.file)
    res.json({
        success: "uploaded",
       // profile_url: `http://localhost:5005/profile/${req.file.filename}`
    })
}
```

for above code i am getting req.file undefined and getting headers as :

```
    'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost:4000',
      'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
      'x-forwarded-port': '4000',
      'x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
      cookie: 'rTFdNeE1EY3lpTSJ9; express:sess.sig=xs4Q-LVeSKTj5SAvax869CN9hww; ui- 
  localhost%3A8091=27b9bf',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, 
    deflate, br',
      referer: 'http://localhost:4000/project/create',      
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      origin: 'http://localhost:4000',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
      Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',      
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 
      accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',  
      'content-length': '0',    
      connection: 'close',      
      host: 'localhost:5005'    
    }
```

but from postman i am getting req.file like this

```
fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'ninjaCoder.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: './upload/images',
  filename: 'file_1621371140733.png',        
  path: 'upload\\images\\file_1621371140733.png',
  size: 169423
```

can anyone help to get out of this issue?
i am using vue version 2.6.12
and node js v14.16.1

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to POST request any router from your vue.js application without an error or weird behaviour?

Comment: other request is working i can fetch, edit, post but only for image i m getting this isuue with response 400 as bad request

Comment: Hmm, that seems like something related to your client side form data or serialization of it. I'm sorry I don't have not much of idea.

Comment: You definitely need to set the content type header to multipart/form-data - you can also try adding a third parameter to the formData.append - formData.append("file", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name) - the selectedFile if a file object should have a name property.

Comment: tried that also but getting same result for req.file and headers. could not get data of formData to backend as well.